# CreateSite throws error Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

We are facing an unusual problem, and its limited to few Tenants.

**Scenario**: We are trying to create site collections using below code

```
try
{
    var tenant = new Tenant(adminContext);
    var properties = new SiteCreationProperties()
    {
        Url = webUrl,
        Owner = siteOwner,
        Title = title,
        Template = SiteTemplate,
        StorageMaximumLevel = StorageMaximumLevel,
        UserCodeMaximumLevel = UserCodeMaximumLevel
    };
    SpoOperation op = tenant.CreateSite(properties);
    adminContext.Load(tenant);
    adminContext.Load(op, i => i.IsComplete);
    adminContext.ExecuteQuery();

    while (!op.IsComplete)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
        op.RefreshLoad();
        adminContext.ExecuteQuery();

    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    string msg = ex.Message;
}
```

On the UAT environment suddenly since yesterday `CreateSite` throws below error.

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Has anyone come across this?

Comment: Did you check with your tenant? if it is ok may issue with you tenant, check the tenant health from admin center.

Comment: We have with our tenant the same issue. I've checked the Service Health and all are green and healty.